# storyboard push segue isn't properly animated

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, storyboard, segue

I'm new to iOS development and don't get on well with storyboard.

screenshot of storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9VTB.png

I have got the push segue working now. But only pushing from the first tableViewController to the second one is animated and pushing back isn't animated.

In the first tableViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"xxx" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"xxx"]) {
        // set some properties of segue.destinationViewController
    }
}
```

the second one is not modified.

---

Update:
I deleted the storyboard, did all of them programmatically and now everything works well.
Sometimes storyboard is just so confusing...

Comment: If you have solved your question, please answer it below and accept the answer. Placing the answer in the question by editing is not how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the segue is animated will depend on how you do it. Try:

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it doesn't work. and i just noticed that the navigationBar is animated but the tableView isn't... how strange it is